# Probability of a tough committee

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A committee of three judges is randomly selected from among ten judges. Four of the ten judges are tough; the committee is tough if at least two of the judges on the committee are tough.
>
> A committee decides whether to approve petitions it receives. A tough committee approves 50% of petitions and a committee that is not tough approves 80% of petitions.
>
> (a) Find the probability a committee is tough.
>
> (b) Find the probability a petition is approved.
>
> (c) Suppose a petition can be submitted many times until it is approved. If a petition is approved with probability 3/4 each time, what is the mean number of times it has to be submitted until it is approved?

For selection of tough committee, I approached taking (4c2 / 10 * 1/10) + 4c3 / 10 = 0.46.

For B, I considered the below P(tough & approved) or P(not tough and approved) 0.46*0.50 + 0.80*(1-0.46)= 0.662.

I dont know if this is the right approacha dnim stuck at the third question

Comment: For selection of tough committee, I approached taking 

(4c2 / 10 * 1/10) + 4c3 / 10 = 0.46.

For B, I considered the below

P(tough & approved) or P(not tough and approved)
0.46*0.50 + 0.80*(1-0.46)= 0.662.

I dont know if this is the right approacha dnim stuck at the third question

Comment: @ChongSu Put this in your opening question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Well the total number of committees is$\ 10C3$ and the number of 'tough' committees is$\ (4C2)*(6C1) + (4C3)$ so therefore the probability of a tough committee is$\ (4C2*6+4C3)/(10C3) = 1/3 $

B) There is a 1/3 chance the comittee is tough, which correlates to a 50% chance of approval, and a 2/3 chance of a not tough comittee, which leads to a 80% chance of approval.

Hence, the probability of approval is $\ (1/3)*(1/2) + (2/3)*(4/5)=70%$

Answer (score 0):

> > A committee of three judges is randomly selected from among ten judges. Four of the ten judges are tough; the committee is tough if at least two of the judges on the committee are tough. A committee decides whether to approve petitions it receives. A tough committee approves 50% of petitions and a committee that is not tough approves 80% of petitions.
> >
> > (a) Find the probability a committee is tough.
>
> For selection of tough committee, I approached taking (4c2 / 10 * 1/10) + 4c3 / 10 = 0.46.

Think again. You want the probability for selecting either: two from four tough and one from six soft judges, or three from four tough judges, when selecting any three from all ten judges.

$$\dfrac{{}^4\mathrm C_2\cdot \phantom{{}^6\mathrm C_1}+{}^4\mathrm C_3 \cdot\phantom{{}^6\mathrm C_0}}{{}^{10}\mathrm C_3} = \dfrac{\phantom{76}}{120} = \phantom{0.6\dot3}$$

> For B, I considered the below P(tough & approved) or P(not tough and approved) 0.46*0.50 + 0.80*(1-0.46)= 0.662.

Yes.   That is the correct *approach*, just not the correct numbers.